# Class is not abstract and does not implement abstract member ERROR while compiling Android project

Tags: java, android, kotlin

While trying to recompile an old project (2 years ago compiled no problem) get error:

Class 'Device' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel, p1: Int): Unit defined in android.os.Parcelable

Also get error: 'writeToParcel' overrides nothing

Please help!

My Device.kt:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable

data class Device(
    val device: BluetoothDevice,
    val rssi: Int = 0): Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readParcelable(BluetoothDevice::class.java.classLoader)!!,
        parcel.readInt()
    )

    override fun describeContents() = 0

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        dest?.writeParcelable(device, flags)
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Device> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Device {
            return Device(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Device?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

My gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.astar.osterrig.controlrelay"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    namespace 'com.astar.osterrig.controlrelay'
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.6'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.6'
    implementation 'eo.view:signalstrength:2.0.0'

    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android:ble:2.3.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

module gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.6'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Class 'Device' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel, p1: Int): Unit defined in android.os.Parcelable

The reason is that the first argument from the base function is interpreted as non-nullable, therefore in the overridden function it should be non-nullable as well, otherwise it's a different function (function arguments are [invariant](https://typealias.com/concepts/invariance/) in Kotlin) that 'overrides nothing'.

Please change the `writeToParcel()` implementation to the following:

```
override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    dest.writeParcelable(device, flags)
}
```

> 2 years ago compiled no problem

Back then, this argument wasn't annotated with `@NonNull`. Therefore, it was interpreted as a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types), that's why it was possible to override it as either `Parcel` or `Parcel?`. It received this annotation in Android SDK 33, and this change reflected your project when the `compileSdk` was changed to 33 or higher, as this version determines the `android.jar` the project compiles against.